# Autoload sql query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a table in a database config_table and I need to get data from it and then send it to the view everytime the site is opened. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom config files into the config/ directory - that would be a much better way to work with config values.

What you're describing is technically possible by extending the core, but it would be much more complicated, so I'd avoid that route if at all possible.

[Config Class Documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/config.html)